# How to create a daterange type with FactoryGirl in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, factory-bot, factory, date-range

I need to create some sample data for one of the models in my application that has a `:daterange` type in my PostgreSQL DB. When creating the seed file for the development ENV I created them like this:

`the_year_range = Date.new(2005).beginning_of_year..Date.new(2009).end_of_year`

which works as expected.

For testing purposes I need to create the same in the testDB. I have tried different things with FactoryGirl, unfortunately without any success.

I have tried things like:

```
factory :first_factory, class: MyModel do
  the_year_range "2004..2009"
end
```

and

```
factory :first_factory, class: MyModel do
  the_year_range do
    start_year = Date.new(2004).beginning_of_year
    end_year   = Date.new(2009).end_of_year

    start_year..end_year
  end
end
```

For both the result will be the same:

`-Infinity..Infinity`

How can I get this to work like in development?

Comment: You can use faker gem date. refer this http://www.rubydoc.info/github/stympy/faker/Faker/Date

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy Faker only creates a single Time object and not a range. Are you suggesting to use this in the way I showed above to create a range of that?

Comment: may i know the type of `the_year_range` field? @Severin

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy The type is `daterange` as described here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html